# Array index changes case when connecting to MySQL on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When I connect my local working copy (Windows 7, WAMP, Apache 2.2, MySQL 5.1, PHP 5.3, CakePHP 2.4) to the local MySQL database, it gives me the following error:

`Notice (8): Undefined index: Asset [APP\Controller\AssetsController.php, line 241]`

Note, when connecting to the remote `RHEL MySQL 5.1` server, the issue does **not** present itself.

Code in question:

`Line 241:   'EnvironmentDeploymentStatus.asset_id'=>$conf['Asset']['asset_id'],`

When connected to the `RHEL MySQL 5.1`, doing `var_dump($conf)`, I'll get this:

```
array (size=3)
  'Asset' => 
    array (size=6)
```

When connected to the `localhost Windows MySQL 5.1`, doing  `var_dump($conf)`, I'll get this (notice the case change in the array key):

```
array (size=3)
  'asset' => 
    array (size=6)
```

The view that populates `$conf` contains this:

```
...
from    
    (((((((`assets` `asset`
...
```

I put in the following configuration in my local MySQL's `my.ini` file:
`lower_case_table_names=2`

The tables are already in lower case (and meet CakePHP standards), I don't think this has any impact on what I'm doing however.

Comment: Is this affecting all models or just Assets?

Comment: @isick in this specific instance, seemed to only be that one. Would like to note, I re-imported with the setting at 0, reloaded my page and the key now has an upper case first letter.

Comment: Very strange. I wonder if it was reading cache or something after you first made the change... Anyway, glad it's resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `lower_case_table_names = 2` is probably your problem. It says in the docs

> This option also applies to database names **and table aliases**.

*(emphasis added)*

[MySQL Doc on lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)

Which means MySQL is changing the table alias provided by Cake to its lowercase version.

The solution is to set this value back to recommended value of 1.

Comment: it was doing this behavior before I put lower_case_table_names to 2. I changed it to this, hoping to rectify the issue. Now, it's at 1, and it still does the same thing. I removed it entirely, and it would seem that 1 is the default.

Comment: Can you try making it 0? This doc says the default on Unix is 0 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: the same document states that one shouldn't be setting this to 0 on Windows, something about index corruption.

Comment: I think that's only for the MyISAM engine - that's how I read it. I guess I was assuming you were on InnoDB - it's the default now, right?

Comment: Other developers sometimes leave their tables in MyISAM, when they should be in InnoDB. I'm just wondering what could happen between the time someone spots this and converts them to InnoDB. In the context of my applications and that it's a local copy, I think this might actually work. In any case, I've set it to 0, but keep seeing a lower case "asset". I've confirmed that in Workbench, the value is at 0.

Comment: I wonder if I should re-import my backup with the new settings on?

Comment: "Other developers sometimes leave their tables in MyISAM, when they should be in InnoDB." Then check their commits and yell at them. :) Or use a migration plugin for CakePHP (rollbacks for the win) or use an external migration tool like Liquibase to manage database schema and data changes. For the migration plugin I think you could create a base class (not tried but should be doable) that enforces InnoDB when the tables are created. So they can't do it wrong.